# Why does changing directory within a python script affect displaying context in pdb?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

Changing directories within a script seems to prevent `pdb` from displaying the current line while stepping through code. Compare the scripts and output below.

```
import os
import pdb
os.chdir('..')
print 'hello'
pdb.set_trace()
print 'world'
```

outputs:

```
hello
/Users/username/test.py(6)<module>()
(pdb)
```

By contrast,

```
import os
import pdb
print 'hello'
pdb.set_trace()
print 'world'
```

outputs:

```
hello
/Users/username/test.py(5)<module>()
-> print 'world'
(pdb)
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way to prevent it (i.e., to get `pdb` to continue print the current line in a script with `os.chdir`)?

Comment: Your two code examples appear to be the same.

Comment: Sorry, the second case should have the `os.chdir` line removed. I'll correct it now.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Both versions for me show the same output.

Comment: Interesting. I'm having this issue on two different machines (both with Python 2.7.12). Thanks for trying to reproduce it, though!

Comment: `pdb` can sometimes get confused if files change during the run.  Is there possibly an old `.pyc` file around?  Are you rerunning the script in a fresh interpreter each time?

Comment: Yup, a fresh interpreter. And no .pyc files.

Answer (score 4):

One cause of this problem is launching a module/script from the current directory.  For example, if I start my script from the shell using:

```
$ ./myscript.py
```

And then myscript uses os.chdir() to change the current working directory pdb will stop printing the current line each time it stops (though list will still work).  On the other hand, if you expand the path to your script before running it like this:

```
$ /Users/me/myproject/myscript.py
```

Then pdb is no longer confused and will print the line source each time it stops.